# Amplifier Vpp calculation

Tags: power, amplifier, rms

If you have an AC input and you want to amplify its amplitude, you have a DC power supply = x Volts , you know the load resistance R, you want to find the maximum RMS power you can get at the output without clipping the wave:

$$P=U\cdot{}I=\frac{U^2}{R}$$

$$V_{rms}=\frac{V_{pp}}{2\cdot\sqrt{2}}$$

therefore \$V_{pp}=x\$

for example:

If the power supply is 12V, the output resistance is 6ohm:

$$V_{pp}=12V$$

$$V_{rms}=\frac{12}{2\cdot\sqrt{2}}=3\cdot\sqrt{2}$$

$$P_{rms}=\frac{V_{rms}^2}{R}=\frac{9\cdot2}{6}= 3W$$

Are my calculations correct?

Comment: Homework, per chance?

Comment: No it's not... I want a single answer: yes or no.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes or no questions are not a good fit for StackExchage. Questions should be helpful for future readers learning electronics.

Comment: You define a few terms in your first sentence, but then the very next equation uses totally different symbols!  Instead of dumping your equations on us, ask what you really want to know in simple terms and we can tell you the equations.  As it stands now, *it is difficult to tell what is being asked here*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

Unfortunately, SE frowns on short answers, so here's some additional discussion.

Your calculation assumes a "perfect" output stage that can swing all the way to the power rails with no loss or distortion. Any real output stage is not going to be able to do that, so you're going to have to reduce V<sub>PP</sub> and the resulting power level accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! I will not post any yes or no questions in future.